# Is the area between Kessex Hills, Gendarran Fields and Lion's Arch reachable?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Well, I always thought it wasn't reachable since it's inhabited by the tengu, blocked off by the Dominion of Winds. But when I browsed through the explored map on the Guild Wars 2 Wiki, I found the area. I had to zoom in a bit, so it's a bit unclear, but I thought by myself, why would they make a map which isn't explorable? Also, some isles (excluding Claw Island) underneath it seem to be reachable. Does anyone know more about this?
See for yourself here: https://wiki.guildwars2.com/images/4/46/Tyria_map_%28clean%29.jpg
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That area is not currently in the game. If it was, you'd be able to find it in the wiki fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the access, [Mistlock Sanctuary](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mistlock_Sanctuary) is an area above that island. So, it is possible to see guild/party members as if they are on the island if you check from your world map. Though, they are actually in the sanctuary.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't reachable, and probably won't be unless they introduce Tengu as a playable race. Lore-wise currently the Tengu follow a strict isolationist policy, that's why we can't visit their lands.